# How to carve a path in a mountain texture?

Tags: sculpting, displacement, height-map

I made a mountain texture using the displacement modifier and a height map image and I want to make a winding road going through it.  But when I use sculpt tools it looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to carve a realistic path with a height map texture or does the height map specifically have to have one built in?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to sculpt on this, apply the displacement modifier first.

Comment: Dang I was hoping I wouldn't have to...the polycount is gonna skyrocket :p

Comment: Copy the mesh and put it on another layer. Then apply the displacement here. You can then do a bake to get all the details on the lowpoly mesh.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I know of baking for physics and animation, but are you saying you can bake the high poly mesh's changes to the low poly?  Is there a tutorial or similar example you can point me to with visuals?

Comment: @lakerice he's probably referring to normal baking to then use the hires normal map on lowres models (easy intro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw)

Comment: i'm sure he is talking about displacement map baking though, if you bake a normal map u wont get that heigth :D
Just a flat plane (unless u do retopo)

Comment: Haha I see how I mixed that up.  Definitely applying the displacement modifier allowed me to do whatever I wanted sculpting-wise.  I also followed the normal map tutorial which sped up my render times considerably...however I found using a procedural rock texture made everything look incredibly realistic up close.  This unfortunately led to long render times again :(

Comment: I will try the displacement map tutorial